# Imagick ALPHA vs OPACITY

Tags: imagemagick, opacity, alpha, imagick

While developping [color-extractor](https://github.com/thephpleague/color-extractor) I stumbled across a quirk with Imagick. I confirmed the issue with a single black transparent pixel image. Under Gimp this black is shown as 75% **opaque** so I guess its alpha/transparency is 25%.

When I run `getColorValue(\Imagick::COLOR_OPACITY)` I get roughly 0.25 whereas I get about 0.75 with `getColorValue(\Imagick::COLOR_ALPHA)` so the exact opposite of what I expected.

Is this an issue about Imagick (I'm using php-imagick 3.4.3-1 and ImageMagick 6.9.7-9) or am I inverting concepts of opacity and transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Not a quirk, but by design. For the most part, opacity & alpha share the same data channel, and the context of the image format / coder implements the correct value. And I stress *context* is key.

> Is this an issue about Imagick [..] or am I inverting concepts of opacity and transparency?

Let's take a look at how the two are implemented.

**PixelGetOpacityQuantum**

```
return(ClampToQuantum(wand->pixel.opacity));
```

**PixelGetAlphaQuantum**

```
return(QuantumRange-ClampToQuantum(wand->pixel.opacity));
```

As you can see, both return the same data bonded between 0 and *Quantum* limit.

The `PixelGetOpacityQuantum` returns the exact data-value, but `PixelGetAlphaQuantum` adjusts/inverts to what we would expect in popular color formats/specs. It's all context!

Comment: I know opacity and transparency are inferred from a unique value but it seems Imagick returns opacity instead of transparency and vice-versa, that is my issue.

Comment: In fact, ImageMagick version 7.x.x is different from ImageMagick 6.x.x in this regard. "We support alpha now, previously opacity" according to http://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php

Comment: I guess this could answer my question but I don't really get the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Correct @GlennRanders-Pehrson ! IM7 focuses on pixel traits, and alpha & opacity are isolated from each other.